# Android On Orientation Change Kaltura Player is not Resumed

Tags: android, ios, kaltura

I am developing the android application in which using Kaltura native android sdk to play the video. [android-native-kaltura-sdk](https://github.com/kaltura/player-sdk-native-android)
I am able to play the video. but when i change the orientation of mobile (*Portrait to Landscape*) player is not resumed.

**Issue is player get restart.**

VideoDetailActivity Class

```
public class VideoDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DraggableListener, OnTaskFinishedListener, KPEventListener {
public boolean isPlaying;

private static final int FULL_SCREEN_FLAG = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
private PlayerFragment mPlayerFragment;

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_detail);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(PlayerFragment.class.getName()) == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, this + ": Existing fragment not found.");
        isPlaying = false;
        mPlayerFragment = new PlayerFragment();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();//.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down);
     // transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, mPlayerFragment, PlayerFragment.class.getName());
        transaction.addToBackStack(mPlayerFragment.getClass().getName());
        transaction.commit();
    } else {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            isPlaying = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isPlaying");
        }
        mPlayerFragment = (PlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(PlayerFragment.class.getName());
        Log.d(TAG, this + ": Existing fragment found.");
    }
}


/**
 * Pause the VideoView content.
 */
private void pauseVideo() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.releaseAndSavePosition();
    }
}

/**
 * Resume the VideoView content.
 */
private void startVideo() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.resumePlayer();
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //player.releaseAndSavePosition();
    mPlayerFragment.pausePlayer();
   // mPlayerFragment.killPlayer();
    outState.putBoolean("isPlaying", isPlaying);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //player.resumePlayer();
    //isPlaying = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isPlaying");
   /* if (isPlaying) {
        mPlayerFragment.resumePlayer();
    }*/
}

public void isPlaying(boolean value) {
    isPlaying = value;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mPlayerFragment != null) {
        mPlayerFragment.killPlayer();
    }
    // if (player != null)
    //player.resumePlayer();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (!isFinishing() && mPlayerFragment != null) {
        //mPlayerFragment.killPlayer();
       /* mPlayerFragment = null;*/
        isPlaying = true;
    }
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        mPlayerFragment.pausePlayer();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

PlayerFragment Class

```
  public class PlayerFragment extends Fragment implements KPEventListener {
private boolean isResumed = false;
private View mFragmentView = null;
private PlayerViewController mPlayerView;
private boolean mFullScreen = true;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public PlayerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static PlayerFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    PlayerFragment fragment = new PlayerFragment();
  /*  Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);*/
    return fragment;
}

public void pausePlayer() {
    mPlayerView.releaseAndSavePosition();

}

public void killPlayer() {
    mPlayerView.removePlayer();
    mPlayerView = null;
    //getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
}


public void resumePlayer() {
    mPlayerView.resumePlayer();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
  /*  if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }*/
    // getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_player, container, false);
    return mFragmentView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mPlayerView = (PlayerViewController) mFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.player);
    mPlayerView.loadPlayerIntoActivity(getActivity());
    if (!((VideoDetailActivity) getActivity()).isPlaying) {
        ((VideoDetailActivity) getActivity()).isPlaying(true);
        KPPlayerConfig config = new KPPlayerConfig("http://cdnapi.kaltura.com", "Player Cofig ID", "Kaltura Partner ID");
        config.setEntryId("Video EntryID");
        mPlayerView.initWithConfiguration(config);
        mPlayerView.addEventListener(this);
    } else {
        mPlayerView.resumePlayer();
    }
}

public void setFullScreen(boolean fullScreen) {
    fullScreen = false;
    if (mFullScreen) {
        Log.v("FullScreen", "-----------Set full screen SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE------------");
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
      /*  int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams) videoSurface.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        params.height=height;
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);*/
        //set icon is full screen
        mFullScreen = fullScreen;
    } else {
        Log.v("FullScreen", "-----------Set small screen SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT------------");
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
       /* final FrameLayout mFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer);
        // int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int height = mFrame.getHeight();//get height Frame Container video
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams) videoSurface.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        params.height= height;
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);*/
        //set icon is small screen
        mFullScreen = !fullScreen;
    }
}


// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onKPlayerStateChanged(PlayerViewController playerViewController, KPlayerState state) {
    switch (state) {
        case READY:
            Log.e("KPlayer State Changed", "Player State  READY :- " + state.toString() + "###################################################################");
            ((VideoDetailActivity) getActivity()).isPlaying(true);
            break;
        case LOADED:
            Log.e("KPlayer State Changed", "Player State  LOADED :- " + state.toString() + "###################################################################");
            break;
        case PAUSED:
            Log.e("KPlayer State Changed", "Player State PAUSED :- " + state.toString() + "###################################################################");
            break;
        case SEEKED:
            Log.e("KPlayer State Changed", "Player State PAUSED :- " + state.toString() + "###################################################################");
            break;
        case SEEKING:
            Log.e("KPlayer State Changed", "Player State PAUSED :- " + state.toString() + "###################################################################");
            break;

    }
}

@Override
public void onKPlayerPlayheadUpdate(PlayerViewController playerViewController, float currentTime) {
    Log.e("KPlayer State Changed", "Player State PAUSED :- " +currentTime + "###################################################################");
}

@Override
public void onKPlayerFullScreenToggeled(PlayerViewController playerViewController, boolean isFullscreen) {
    setFullScreen(isFullscreen);
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

Comment: i m facing same issue. did you find any solution ?